# Integral of $\frac{1}{2x}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Using $u$-substitution,
$$ \int \frac{1}{ax} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\ln|ax|}{a}. $$
However, should you have instead factored out $\frac{1}{a}$ and integrated $\frac{1}{x}$, your result would be
$$\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{ \ln|x| }{a}. $$

So which is correct?  My personal experience suggests that the latter method is superior, but without $u$-substitution, how would one go about integrating $\frac{1}{ax+b}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange error concerning integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851677/strange-error-concerning-integration-by-parts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $u$-substitution: $u=ax$, so $du=a\ dx$ and
$$\int\frac{1}{ax}dx=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{u}du=\frac{\ln|u|}{a}+C=\frac{\ln|ax|}{a}+C=\frac{\ln|x|}{a}+\frac{\ln|a|}{a}+C=\frac{\ln|x|}{a}+D$$
Putting the factor out:
$$\int\frac{1}{ax}dx=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\ln|x|}{a}+C$$

To integrate $\frac{1}{ax+b}$, use $u=ax+b$, so again $du=a\ dx$ and
$$\int\frac{1}{ax+b}dx=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{u}du=\frac{\ln|u|}{a}+C=\frac{\ln|ax+b|}{a}+C$$
(which may also be rewritten as $\frac{\ln|x+\frac{b}{a}|}{a}+D$)

Answer (score 4):

They're both correct: $$\frac{\ln|ax|}{a}=\frac{\ln|a|+\ln|x|}{a}
=\frac{\ln|x|}a+c.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{\ln|ax|}{a}-\frac{ \ln|x| }{a}=\frac1a\ln\frac{|ax|}{|x|}=\frac1a\ln|a|=c$$